# Google crawler indexed homepage, but not the internal links on it

Tags: seo, google-search-console

Google Search Console tells me my homepage is successfully indexed, but that's the only one. Homepage has around 25 internal links, all working properly, and none of those show on "coverage" tab.

HTML from the crawled page (indexed HTML) shows all the links correctly.

**Why hasn't it indexed the internal links, if homepage seems to be successfully rendered and indexed by crawler?**

I use javascript to fetch content via ajax for each link, but that shouldn't be a problem since google bot is able to execute js for some time now. (right?)

Also, I could use sitemaps, but I'd like to go "clean" and let the crawler do its thing.

URL is https://www.canadastepbystep.com, if that helps.

**Update**:
I've fixed a previous problem (see my own answer below), and now all the links work as landing pages. But still same problem - yesterday homepage got indexed again and same thing - it didn't indexed any of the links.

Answer (score 1):

I've just realized that all linked pages expect a cookie (created on homepage) to render properly. 
Googlebot doesn't accept cookies, so that breaks the whole thing.

Currently working on a fix.

Comment: You absolutely need to fix that.  It would cause problems with more than just crawling.   Once Google indexed your deep page, Google would send visitors directly there.   Users from search engines need to be able to land on any page on your site without viewing the home page first.